# Loop through WebBrowsers

Tags: c#

This code works for single webBrowser1

```
    HtmlElementCollection links = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a");

    foreach (HtmlElement link in links)
    {
        if (link.OuterHtml.ToString().Contains("E-mail"))
        {
            link.InvokeMember("click");
        }
    }
```

But I would like to use it for each webBrowser, so I menaged something like that:

```
    foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
    {

        WebBrowser t = c as WebBrowser;

        HtmlElementCollection links = t.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a");
        foreach (HtmlElement link in links)
        {
            if (link.OuterHtml.ToString().Contains("E-mail"))
            {
                link.InvokeMember("click");
            }
        }
    }
```

But it says that `"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`c` is a different control than a web browser so the `as` cast fails. You can use [`OfType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913(v=vs.110).aspx) to only get the web browsers

```
foreach (var c in this.Controls.OfType<WebBrowser>())
```

Otherwise you need to handle the `NullReferenceException`

```
WebBrowser t = c as WebBrowser;
if(t == null)
    continue;
```

Comment: Do you have any idea why it start enumerate from last one? If I use `foreach` and `Navigate` every webBrowser to other website it start from last webbrowser (for example webBrowser5) to first.

Comment: @HamBurg - I'm not 100% sure but I think it relates to the tab order of the controls since the [Remarks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls(v=vs.110).aspx) hint at this is what `GetNextControl` uses, otherwise its probably the position of the element on the form which may affect the order in which the designer cs adds them to the collection